# Python using AND with regex

Tags: python, regex

So I have looked around the internet for like 20 minutes and I haven't been able to figure it out. Is it possible to use AND in regex, or something similar (I've just started learning about regex)?

For example, I have the string "finksdssfsk32residogs" and I want to get the output: "32 dogs". I've tried using re.search, re.match, and re.findall but I haven't had any luck. I've tried things like:

```
re.findall(r"(\d{2})(dogs)", str)
re.search(r"(\d{2})(dogs)", str)
```

And I've tried a few combinations of each. And I know I can do this with multiple lines but the goal is to get "32 dogs" from "finksdssfsk32residogs" with only one line. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `(\d{2}).*?(dogs)` : https://regex101.com/r/cSF55l/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it. You just need some space between the numbers and the dogs.

Can you just match anything? How about `(\d{2}).*(dogs)`? Then you can replace the middle part with a space using join:

```
>>> print(' '.join(re.search(r'(\d{2}).*(dogs)', 'finksdssfsk32residogs').groups()))
32 dogs
```